# Crossfire issues: not using both cards in some programs/games

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card, crossfire

I am running two HD 7970s in crossfire on my windows 10 rig. Through afterburner I can see that both cards are working in tandem when bench marking and in most games. However, I have noticed in a few games, Skyrim mainly, that only the master is utilized when playing. The slave card usage does jump up a little bit when first loading different areas, however, it quickly drops back to zero and stays there.

Are there some games that just can't use crossfire? Is there some setting I am unaware of?

[image]

Comment: Any application must be programmed to take advantage of Crossfire or SLI. That isn't the case of the [program](http://enbseries.enbdev.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=509) in question though

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't been having any of those issues though. The game runs pretty well. Well, sub 60fps. I just don't know why the second card isn't being used.

Comment: Did you try to adjust the game profile?  I linked to that thread for a reason.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ya, I have been playing around with the gaming profile in Radeon settings. No luck so far.